# Como converter Libras em Euros VBA?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

CONVERSÃO:
A conversão será o valor em Libras x 1,17 = Valor em Euros.
Para que possa adicionar uma percentagem a formula será Libras x 1,17 x (1 + percentagem).

MÉTODO APLICADO:
Substituição da coluna de libras 200`.`50 para 250`,`50 e só depois aplico a formula.

Pretendo que o valor final seja com `.` e não `,`, alguma ideia?

Comment: Na verdade se você usa um separador o Excel vai usar esta mesma configuração para todas as suas planilhas... portanto, se quiser usar 1,17, poderia usar 1.17 e fazer o cálculo, sem ter de converter ou mudar o tipo de separador... respondi e repensei sobre sua pergunta.. que se for a dúvida de como mudar o separador em VBA ai está, caso seja isso, poderia tualizar a pergunta para ficar mais claro. Abs e boa sorte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mudar essas configurações em VBA utilize a função abaixo, alterando conforme deseja:

```
Sub mudaSeparador() 

 Range("A1").Formula = "1,234,567.89" 

 ' Defina os separadores que deseja
 Application.DecimalSeparator = "-" ' > Separador para decimal
 Application.ThousandsSeparator = "-" ' > Separador para milhar
 Application.UseSystemSeparators = False 

End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff195207.aspx

Comment: Eu alterei a definição decimal em Painel de Controlo > Região e Idioma > Definições Adicionais > Separador Decimal.

Comment: Mas sem dúvida @Evert, dessa forma fica mais fácil transportar o livro.